# Deserialize XML with repeating elements

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

This is C# in VS2012 and building against .NET 4.5

I'm new to XML serialization/deserialization and trying to figure this out.  I have XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AvailabilityResponse>
  <ApiKey>LZ6c@3O9#tq*BAyX4KGYBsCgZ*HpUDtrB*XI*WGLw</ApiKey>
  <ResellerId>101</ResellerId>
  <SupplierId>1004</SupplierId>
  <ForeignReference>1234567890</ForeignReference>
  <Timestamp>2015-08-06T05:20:49.000Z</Timestamp>
  <RequestStatus>
      <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
  </RequestStatus>
  <TTAsku>dcnt</TTAsku>
  <TourAvailability>
      <TourDate>2015-08-31</TourDate>
      <TourOptions>
          <DepartureTime>07:30 PM</DepartureTime>
      </TourOptions>
      <AvailabilityStatus>
          <Status>AVAILABLE</Status>
      </AvailabilityStatus>
  </TourAvailability>
  <TourAvailability>
      <TourDate>2015-08-31</TourDate>
      <TourOptions>
          <DepartureTime>08:30 PM</DepartureTime>
      </TourOptions>
      <AvailabilityStatus>
          <Status>AVAILABLE</Status>
      </AvailabilityStatus>
  </TourAvailability>
</AvailabilityResponse>
```

and I'm trying to deserialize into this class structure:

```
[Serializable]
public class AvailabilityResponse
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string ResellerId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string ForeignReference { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public RequestStatus RequestStatus { get; set; }
    public string TTAsku { get; set; }
    public TourAvailability[] TourAvailability { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class RequestStatus
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class TourAvailability
{
    public DateTime TourDate { get; set; }
    public TourOptions TourOptions { get; set; }
    public AvailabilityStatus AvailabilityStatus { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class AvailabilityStatus
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string UnavailabilityReason { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm doing so with:

```
public static AvailabilityResponse DeserializeAvailabilityResponse(Stream replyStream)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSr = null;
    XmlReader inreader = null;

    if (replyStream != null)
    {
        XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(replyStream);
        XmlDocument respXml = new XmlDocument();
        respXml.Load(xmlreader);
        xmlreader.Close();

        xmlSr = DeserializeXmlDoc(respXml, out inreader, typeof(AvailabilityResponse));
    }

    if (xmlSr != null && inreader != null)
    {
        AvailabilityResponse inventory = (AvailabilityResponse)xmlSr.Deserialize(inreader);
        return inventory;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that when I examine the returned inventory item, the `TourAvailability` looks like this:
    [image]
where I expected it to be like RequestStatus, for example, with the [+] allowing me to open it and see each element.  Even if I misrepresented it I would expect there to be at least one TourAvailability, not zero.

I'm probably missing several things here but any help you can give is greatly appreciated.  I have a bunch more of this kind of thing to deal with because our company is slightly changing direction.

Comment: I don't see `AvailabilityStatus` defined.  What's its structure?

Comment: You can make sure you have your classes structured correctly by copying the xml to the clipboard then doing an Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes from visual studio into a new class file.

Comment: Added AvailabiltiyStatus in the original question.

Comment: I didn't know that @Crowcoder  thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `[XmlElement("TourAvailability")]` attribute, Then you'll see the array's elemets.

```
public class AvailabilityResponse
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string ResellerId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string ForeignReference { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public RequestStatus RequestStatus { get; set; }
    public string TTAsku { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TourAvailability")]
    public TourAvailability[] TourAvailability { get; set; }
}
```

BTW: You don't need those `[Serializable]` attributes

PS: Your deserialization code can be simplified as:

```
using (var f = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AvailabilityResponse));
    var resp = (AvailabilityResponse)ser.Deserialize();
}
```

Comment: I tried that before but it kept saying that it was inaccessible due to some protection problem.  It's probably my screwy code.  I used the Past XML as Classes as suggested and it's working now with minimal adjusting after doing that!

Comment: Thanks for the info about the Serializable attributes and simplifying my code.  Since this was the only formal answer and you helped educate me and it seems like your solution would have worked if my other code was good I'm accepting this answer.  Thanks for all y'all's help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stream stream = File.Open(FILENAME, FileMode.Open);
            AvailabilityResponse availabilityResponse = DeserializeAvailabilityResponse(stream);
        }
        public static AvailabilityResponse DeserializeAvailabilityResponse(Stream replyStream)
        {
            AvailabilityResponse availabilityResponse = null;
            XmlReader inreader = null;

            if (replyStream != null)
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AvailabilityResponse));
                inreader = new XmlTextReader(replyStream);
                availabilityResponse = (AvailabilityResponse)xs.Deserialize(inreader);
                return availabilityResponse;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("AvailabilityResponse")]
    public class AvailabilityResponse
    {
        [XmlElement("ApiKey")]
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ResellerId")]
        public int ResellerId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("SupplierId")]
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ForeignReference")]
        public string ForeignReference { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RequestStatus")]
        public RequestStatus RequestStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TTAsku")]
        public string TTAsku { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TourAvailability")]
        public List<TourAvailability> TourAvailability { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("RequestStatus")]
    public class RequestStatus
    {
        [XmlElement("Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("TourAvailability")]
    public class TourAvailability
    {
        [XmlElement("TourDate")]
        public DateTime TourDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TourOptions")]
        public TourOptions TourOptions { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("AvailabilityStatus")]
        public AvailabilityStatus AvailabilityStatus { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("TourOptions")]
    public class TourOptions
    {
        public DateTime dTime { get; set; }


        [XmlElement("DepartureTime")]
        public string DepartureTime
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");
            }
            set
            {
                this.dTime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }


    }

    [XmlRoot("AvailabilityStatus")]
    public class AvailabilityStatus
    {
        [XmlElement("Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("UnavailabilityReason")]
        public string UnavailabilityReason { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```